# Django changes the MEDIA URL if I pass request from views to serializer

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, backend

I am working on a Social Media project. I successfully implemented image upload and now working on Like model which allows users to like a post.

At present state, if a user clicks on Like button, it turns red. All I want is if the page reloads or the same user logins again, the specific post's like button must remain red.

In order to achieve so, I am trying to add extra field in serializer(below): `liked_by_current_user` with which I can filter out as to when the like color must be red. (The REST APIs are working correctly)

`models.py:`

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField(max_length=200)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    profile_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='user_image', null=True, blank=True)

class Like(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

selected `views.py`

```
def feed(request):
    context = {
        'MEDIA_URL': settings.MEDIA_URL,  # pass MEDIA_URL to the template
    }
    return render(request, 'post_list_temp.html', context)

class PostListView(APIView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        posts = Post.objects.filter(deleted=False).order_by('-created_on')
        context = {
            'post_list' : posts,

        }
        paginator = defPagination()
        result = paginator.paginate_queryset(posts, request, view=self)
        serializer = feedSerializer(result, context={"request":request},  many=True)
        return paginator.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            print(request)
            serializer = postPostSerializer(data=request.data)
            if serializer.is_valid():
                serializer.save(author=request.user)
            else:
                print(serializer.errors)
            return Response({"Status":"Posted"})
        else:
            return Response({"Status":"You are not logged in."})
```

`serializer`:

```
class feedSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    author = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='author.username')
    likes_count = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    liked_by_current_user = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['id', 'body', 'author', 'media', 'likes_count', 'created_on']

    def get_likes_count(self, obj):
        return obj.like_set.count()

    def get_liked_by_current_user(self, obj):
        request = self.context['request']  # Get request object from context
        user = request.user  # Get current user from request
        if user.is_authenticated:
            try:
                like = Like.objects.get(user=user.userprofile, post=obj)
                return True
            except Like.DoesNotExist:
                return False
        return False
```

But here, when I pass `context = {'request': request}` from view to serializer, the MEDIA URL in frontend console changes from example `https://127.0.0.1:8000/media/post_image/test.jpg` to `/media/127.0.0.1:8000/media/post_image/test.jpg` due to which images are not displayed.

`settings.py`:

```
MEDIA_ROOT =  os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Why is this happening? And how to avoid it?

I tried implementing this functionality without backend using the localStorage of React. But it has its own problems.

Comment: Shown serializer serializes model `Post` which isn't shown. `MEDIA URL in frontend` how does frontend handle `MEDIA_URL`, what is the reason of passing it  _there and back_? `I tried implementing this functionality using the localStorage` which functionality? serialization of Post items, "red button"? You did not show any code connected to media files handling. `Why is this happening?` sorry, but no idea. Please rewrite your question to bring some clarity.